# how to remove border(outline) coming on custom DropDownIndicator image in react-select?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

here I've used a a custom dropdown Indicator

```
const DropdownIndicator = props => (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
        <img className="arrow-down-grey" />
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
);
```

here I'm returning the select component

```
<Select
   value={formOptions[0].value}
   options={formOptions}
   styles={selectTableStyles}
   components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
/>
```

[Here is the screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk8Nr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Does this css do the trick for you  ?

```
.arrow-down-grey {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: this is not working